# Find layergroup of a specific layer in photoshop with javascript

Tags: javascript, photoshop, layer, psd, jsx

Is any way to retrieve the name of a layer group only for the name on a inner layer? I ask this because I'm trying to trim all the content of a folder with a specific layer inside. Can I get any help please?

Answer (score 4):

If the layer name and the group name are both unique then you can retrieve it simply with:

```
app.activeDocument.activeLayer = app.activeDocument.layerSets.getByName("my group name").artLayers.getByName("my layer name");
```

Where "my group name" is the name of the group and "my layer name" is the name of the layer within "my group name".